# Remove rubber nut from wiper motor arm?

Tags: chevrolet, windshield-wipers

How do I remove the control arm from the wiper motor? All videos I've seen show the motor removed with the short actuator arm still attached (via the only real nut I can see. Also I'm not sure if that nut is left hand threads but it just fights me anyway and turns). Do I just destroy the (pressure fit?) rubber nut to get it lose? '91 Chevy Astro.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Fixed. Turns out, the new one doesn't come with an actuator arm, so I undid the bolt (which was not left hand threads) by grasping the arm with a wrench. I am still curious as to how that rubber fastener works.